# Properly crop an image obtained from the photo library

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgimage, alassetslibrary, alasset

I've been working on this all day, and have looked at lots of questions here on SO and google, but so far I can't come up with anything quite right.

I have taken a photo on an iPad running iOS 5.1.1 and cropped it using the Photos app.  I then get a reference to it from the assets library and am getting the full resolution image which is un-cropped.

I've found that the cropping information is contained in the `AdjustmentXMP` key of `metadata` on my `ALAssetRepresentation` object.

So I crop the photo using the XMP info and here is what I get:

Original Photo (1,936 x 2,592):
[image: Original Photo]

Properly Cropped Photo, as seen in the Photos App (1,420 x 1,938):
[image: Properly Cropped Photo]

Photo Cropped With Code Below
(also 1,420 x 1,938 but cropped roughly 200 pixels too far to the right):
[image: Problem]

This is the XMP data from the photo:

```
<x:xmpmeta xmlns:x="adobe:ns:meta/" x:xmptk="XMP Core 4.4.0">
   <rdf:RDF xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#">
      <rdf:Description rdf:about=""
            xmlns:aas="http://ns.apple.com/adjustment-settings/1.0/">
         <aas:AffineA>1</aas:AffineA>
         <aas:AffineB>0</aas:AffineB>
         <aas:AffineC>0</aas:AffineC>
         <aas:AffineD>1</aas:AffineD>
         <aas:AffineX>-331</aas:AffineX>
         <aas:AffineY>-161</aas:AffineY>
         <aas:CropX>0</aas:CropX>
         <aas:CropY>0</aas:CropY>
         <aas:CropW>1938</aas:CropW>
         <aas:CropH>1420</aas:CropH>
      </rdf:Description>
   </rdf:RDF>
</x:xmpmeta>
```

Here is the code that I am using to crop the photo:

```
ALAssetRepresentation *rep = // Get asset representation
CGImageRef defaultImage = [rep fullResolutionImage];

// Values obtained from XMP data above:
CGRect cropBox = CGRectMake(0, 0, 1938, 1420);
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, 1, 331, 161);

// Apply the Affine Transform to the crop box:
CGRect transformedCropBox =  CGRectApplyAffineTransform(cropBox, transform);

// Created a new cropped image:
CGImageRef croppedImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect(defaultImage, transformedCropBox);

// Create the UIImage:
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:croppedImage scale:[rep scale] orientation:[rep orientation]];

CGImageRelease(croppedImage);
```

I've reproduced the problem with multiple images. If I just use the `fullScreenImage` it displays perfectly, but I need the full size image.

Comment: What are the sizes of those images (all three of them), and of `fullResolutionImage`? And what is `[rep scale]` and `[rep orientation]`?  (I suspect StackOverflow resized your images, but it's impossible to know for sure.)

Comment: @KurtRevis: Well, I just took screen shots to show what it looked like, so don't use these images.  I'll just added the sizes to the question though, thanks!

Comment: @KurtRevis: Oh, and the `fullResolutionImage` is the first photo.  `scale` is 1.0 and `orientation` is 3.  The crop box is supposed to be applied to the un-rotated image though.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a tricky one! There is apparently no documentation for this XMP data, so we'll have to guess at how to interpret it. There are a number of choices to make, and getting it wrong can lead to subtly wrong results.

**TL;DR: In theory your code looks correct, but in practice it's giving the wrong result, and there's a fairly obvious adjustment we can try.**

### Orientation

Image files may contain additional metadata specifying whether (and how) the raw data of the image should be rotated and/or flipped when displayed. `UIImage` expresses this with its [`imageOrientation`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIImage/imageOrientation) property, and [`ALAssetRepresentation` is similar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AssetsLibrary/Reference/ALAssetRepresentation_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/ALAssetRepresentation/orientation).

However, `CGImage`s are just bitmaps, with no orientation stored in them. `-[ALAssetRepresentation fullResolutionImage]` gives you a `CGImage` in the original orientation, with no adjustments applied.

In your case, the orientation is `3`, meaning `ALAssetOrientationRight` or `UIImageOrientationRight`. The viewing software (for instance, `UIImage`) looks at this value, sees that the image is oriented 90° to the right (clockwise), then rotates it by 90° to the left (counterclockwise) before displaying it. Or, to say it another way, the `CGImage` is rotated 90° clockwise from the image you're looking at on your screen.

(To verify this, get the width and height of the CGImage by using `CGImageGetWidth()` and `CGImageGetHeight()`. You should find that the CGImage is 2592 wide and 1936 high. This is rotated 90° from the `ALAssetRepresentation`, whose `dimensions` should be 1936 wide by 2592 high. You could also create a `UIImage` from the `CGImage` using the normal orientation `UIImageOrientationUp`, write the `UIImage` to a file, and see what it looks like.)

The values in the XMP dictionary appear to be relative to the `CGImage`'s orientation. For instance, the crop rect is wider than it is tall, the X translation is greater than the Y translation, etc.  Makes sense.

### Coordinate system

We also have to decide what coordinate system the XMP values are supposed to be in. Most likely it's one of these two:

- ["Cartesian"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system): origin is at the bottom-left corner of the image, X increases to the right, and Y increases upwards. This is system that Core Graphics usually uses.
- "Flipped": origin is at the top-left corner of the image, X increases to the right, and Y increases downwards. This is the system that UIKit usually uses. Surprisingly, unlike most of CG, [`CGImageCreateWithImageInRect()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGImage/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGImageCreateWithImageInRect) interprets its `rect` argument this way.

Let's assume that "flipped" is correct, since it's generally more convenient. Your code is already trying to do it that way, anyway.

### Interpreting the XMP dictionary

The dictionary contains an affine transform and a crop rect. Let's guess that it should be interpreted in this order:

1. Apply the transform
2. Draw the image in its natural rect (0,0,w,h)
3. Un-apply the transform (pop the transform stack)
4. Crop to the crop rect

If we try this by hand, the numbers seem to work out. Here's a rough diagram, with the crop rect in translucent purple:

[image: diagram for flipped case]

### Now for some code

We don't actually have to follow those exact steps, in terms of calling CG, but we should act as if we had.

We just want to call `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`, and it's pretty obvious how to compute the appropriate crop rect `(331,161,1938,1420)`. Your code appears to do this correctly.

If we crop the image to that rect, then create a `UIImage` from it (specifying the correct orientation, `UIImageOrientationRight`), then we should get the correct results.

*But, the results are wrong!*  What you get was *as if* we did the operations in a Cartesian coordinate system:

[image: diagram for cartesian case]

Alternatively, it's as if the image was rotated the opposite direction, `UIImageOrientationLeft`, but we kept the same crop rect:

[image: diagram for oriented-left case]

### A correction

That's all very odd, and I don't understand what went wrong, although I'd love to.

But a fix seems fairly straightforward: just flip the clip rect.  After computing it as above:

```
// flip the transformedCropBox in the image
transformedCropBox.origin.y = CGImageGetHeight(defaultImage) - CGRectGetMaxY(transformedCropBox);
```

Does that work?  (For this case, and for images with other orientations?)

Comment: This works great for all orientations!  Now, I only wonder why we have to do this, and more importantly, why it isn't documented....

Comment: Do you have any complete code that you can post here.  I'm trying to implement this solution and can't seem to interpret this answer fully.